# How can I batch change the types of phone numbers in my Address Book?

Tags: macos, mac, address-book

I have a large Address Book (on Mac 10.5) that has 80% of the phone numbers listed as "other".

When I sync the address book with my server, the "other" numbers aren't included.

Is there a way to batch change all "other" labels to "mobile"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have successfully used the following AppleScript:

```
tell application "Address Book"
    repeat with thisPerson in every person
        try
            repeat with thisPhone in every phone of thisPerson
                if label of thisPhone = "other" then
                    set label of thisPhone to "mobile"
                end if
            end repeat
        on error errorMessage
            log errorMessage
        end try
    end repeat
    save
end tell
```

In short, it changes all `other` phone numbers to `mobile`, which in turn causes the phone number to be synced.

Comment: Hi Vidar. Thank you for Your answer. I did originally find a cumbersome solution of importing everything to Outlook 2011. Here "other" is changed automatically and can then be exported back to address book :-)